# Class square finding of axis

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to find the axis of class Square's axis as shown below? But I've been trying for hours and still did not managed to solve it. Can someone with their high level expertise show me the ropes to do it? Because both center function call and axis function call in main() does call the same x() and y(), hence brought me to a state of confusion. I know the inheritance of square from circle is weird. But it is what my school wants. Note: Main() CANNOT be modified! Thanks!

Output:

Square::axis test failed

8.87627 0.284967

3.82567 0.958537

Tests passed: 50%

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>


class Object
{
public:

private:
    float d;

public:
    Object(float n) : d(n){}
    Object(){}
    float depth() const
    {
        return d;
    }

    struct PointType
    {
        float x2;
        float y2;
        PointType( float x1,  float y1) :x2(x1),y2(y1){}
        PointType(){}
        float x()
        {
            return x2;
        }
        float y()
        {
            return y2;
        }
        PointType center()
        {
            return *this;
        }

    };
    struct VectorType
    {
        float tx;
        float ty;
        VectorType( float tx1,  float ty1) :tx(tx1),ty(ty1){}
        VectorType(  ){}
    };

    virtual ~Object()
    {}
};
class Point :public Object 
{

private:
    PointType mpoint;

public:

    Point(const PointType& pt, float& y1) :Object(y1), mpoint(pt) {}
    Point(const PointType& pt):mpoint(pt){}
    Point(){}

     Point center() const
    {
         return *this;
    }
     float x()
    {
        return mpoint.x2;

    }
     float y()
    {
        return mpoint.y2;
    }

    virtual ~Point(){}

};
class Circle : public Point 
{ 
    private:
    Object::PointType m_pt;
    float r;
    public:  

    Circle(const PointType pts, float rad, float dep) 
    : Point(m_pt,dep),m_pt(pts),r(rad) {}

    Circle(const PointType pts, float rad):m_pt(pts),r(rad){}

    Circle(){}

    float radius() const
    {
        return r;
    }

    Circle center() const
    {
        return *this;   

    };
     float x()
    {
        return m_pt.x2;

    }
      float y()
    {
        return m_pt.y2;
    }


 };
class Square: public Circle 
{
    private:
    Object::PointType s_pt;
    Object::VectorType v_pt;
    float a=getRadius();

    public:
    Square(const PointType spts,const VectorType vpts,float depth) :
    Circle(spts,a,depth),s_pt(spts),v_pt(vpts){}

    Square(const Object::PointType& spts, const VectorType vpts):s_pt(spts),v_pt(vpts){}

    Square axis() const
    {
        return Square(s_pt,v_pt,getRadius());
    }
    Square center() const
    {
         return *this;
    }

    float radius() const
    {
          return a;
    }
    float getRadius() const
    {
        float rad= sqrt(v_pt.tx * v_pt.tx + v_pt.ty * v_pt.ty); 

        return rad;
    }
    float x() const
    {
        return s_pt.x2;
        // v_pt.tx/radius();
    }
    float y() const

    {
        return s_pt.y2;
        // v_pt.ty/radius();
    }

};

const float EPSILON = 1e-5f;

bool is_near(float x, float y)
{
    return std::abs(x - y) < EPSILON;
}

float frand()
{
    return 10.0f * float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX);
}

int main()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    int count = 0;
    int max_count = 0;

    float x = frand();
    float y = frand();
    float sx = frand();
    float sy = frand();
    float depth = frand();
    Square square(Square::PointType(x, y), Square::VectorType(sx, sy), depth);

    if (is_near(square.center().x(), x) &&
        is_near(square.center().y(), y))
    {
        ++count;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "  - Square::center test failed" << std::endl;
    }

    ++max_count;

    float radius = std::sqrt(sx * sx + sy * sy);
    if (is_near(square.axis().x(), sx / radius) &&
        is_near(square.axis().y(), sy / radius))
    {
        ++count;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "  - Square::axis test failed" << std::endl;
    }
    ++max_count;
    std::cout << square.axis().x()<< " " << sx / radius<<std::endl;
        std::cout << square.axis().y()<< " " <<  sy / radius<<std::endl;
    int result = static_cast<int>(
        100.0f * static_cast<float>(count) / static_cast<float>(max_count) + 0.5f
    );
    std::cout << "Tests passed: " << result << "%" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the code that is not relevant to your problem and post a [mcve].

Comment: @RSahu Alright done. I believe all of them are relevant now. Able to compile.

Comment: Your abstractions are a bit unclear to me. What would be an "axis" of a "square" in a 2D plane?

Comment: @RSahu I am also just as confused and clueless like you.. hence I'm stuck and can't answer ur qns.. Sorry bout that.

Comment: 1) I don't understand the question. 2) The code is definitely not a minimal possible one. `Main() CANNOT be modified!` It's requirement of your instructor, not of StackOverflow. You can and should modify it, removing irrelevant stuff. You should also remove irrelevant methods from all classes (e.g. `operator<<` is a candidate).

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you'll have to get some clarification from your instructor and/or teaching assistant.

Comment: @dyukha Oh ure right, was testing other stuff and neglected that part. Sorry bout that.

Comment: You're telegram style of writing might be cool for whatsapp and such but it's not welcome on this site. U got it? ;-) [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/): _Please write actual words. There are undoubtedly some abbreviations which are acceptable to most readers – IMO, IIRC etc –  there’s no reason to switch into text-speak with “gr8”, “bcoz”, “u” and so forth._